How to Create an Inset with Rounded Curvature
I'm trying to create an inset on a face in Blender, but I want the resulting inset to have a rounded curvature, similar to the shape of a hammock. I have successfully used the Inset tool, but the edges remain straight, and I need them to be smoothly curved.


Given this mesh is generated by importing an SVG and using the Knife Project tool to outset the contour, beveling would be a nightmare. I have the LoopTools add-on enabled, but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed to achieve this effect. Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or any tips on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

You don't need it to be any specific curvature you just want it smoothed out generally? You could just make a displacement map with that svg, Blur the outer area just a bit and then displace the grid that way. You'd need Photoshop or GIMP or something. But its not going to be very clean either way.

This quite easy task for geometry nodes.

I made setup like this. It trims input geometry by Z position, then each point lower than this value sets a new Z position based on distance to the closest point from the trimmed figure.
Roundness of filet controls by float curve node.


I may be way out of my league here, or misunderstanding the question at hand. If i am or if i do, i apologize.
But since you have the SVG file, can't you just reverse it, import the new reversed one, and either extrude the new SVG and bevel it or just run a rounded bevel on it, convert the curve to mesh and run a boolean on the mesh you already have? 

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

@HarryMcKenzie Hi! Sure i can edit it, no problem. Only reason i didn't make a comment is because i wasn't allowed to(?) It said something about 50 points or something. But i'll edit the answer!
